# Codeigniter Sessions not storing in userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My session variables are stored in the session but as new session variables instead of being stored in the user_data array. Can someone help me with this issue? I have not modified any core files.

**Function from my user_model**

```
function login($email, $password){
    $this->db->where(array(
        "email" => $email
    ));

    $user = $this->db->get($this->table)->row_array();

    $checker = hash("SHA256",$password.$user['salt']);

    if($user['password'] != $checker){
        $user = null;
    }


    if($user){
        $this->session->set_userdata("uid", $user['id']);

        redirect("/browse");
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "The credentials you have entered are not correct.");
        redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code as to how you are assigning session data and how you are retrieving it just for peace of mind :p

Comment: CI sessions are stored in 2 ways, in a cookie or in a database table. If you are storing them in a database table you need to make sure that the session values are being written to the db table. If your using cookies (i recommend against this for security reason!), make sure that the cookies are not being blocked by the browser. You can see how to setup the database on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I do have them being saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at code its clear that you are creating a new key name uid if user exists.

If you wanted to store uid inside user_data array you will do this

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user_data", array('uid',$user['id']) );
```

I hope it helps

Comment: So something in codeigniter changed? I've been using $this->session->set_username(name,value) for years and its even says in the documentation to use this format.

Comment: no its same, but if you wanted to store associative array inside a key, you should do as above